# filter data with comma with where clause firestore firebase angular

Tags: angular, firebase

i have field in firestore in which data is stored like this

```
asdasd, chocolates
```

i want to filter data with these tags for example if i send paramter to link like this http://localhost:4200/blogs/tagBlogList/chocolates

i need to get all data who have **'chocolates'** tags

here is my code that i am trying to get data

```
this.featureBlogCollection = this.afs.collection('posts', ref => ref.where("category","array-contains-any",[category]))
     
  
    //this.blogDoc = this.afs.doc<Blog>(`posts/${category}`)

    return this.featureBlogCollection.valueChanges()
```

but i am getting empty data with this code

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your tags as an array, for your code to work correctly :

Instead of saving:

```
asdasd, chocolates
```

You need to save it as

```
['asdasd', 'chocolates']
```

Your code currently is search for the value "chocolates", but it's only finding "asdasd, chocolates" which isn't a match.

You can store as an array by using plain javascript:

```
// Code just before saving your document
let categoriesArray = categoriesString.split(',');
// Optional: Trim whitespace 
categoriesArray = categoriesArray.map((item) => item.trim());
// Attach categories to your entry and save it.
```

For stronger searching you'll have to wire up a 3rd party full text search service of your choice, otherwise, this should work.

Comment: any example how i can story as array?
`category: string
const data = {
     
     category: this.category,
     
    };
this.blogService.create(data)`
this is how i am saving..